# Unable to use unused free space in WIN 7 Disk Management

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I want to add atleast 5 gb space to my win 7 drive [C].

The problem is I am unable to convert/format the contiguous free space for some reason into any type of partition [please see the screenshot link at the end].

When ever I try to convert this free space, i get an error in the end of the process that:

```
---------------------------
Disk Management
---------------------------
There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have tried different option in the wizard, such as no format, using 40-50% less size instead of full 19.53 gb, but still I always get that error.

This has been the case since I clean installed win 7 last December.

And as shown in this image, I am not even allowed to delete this, only 'New Simple Volume' option is available.

Would really appreciate any help, I am open to using third party software if it does it non-destructively [can't spend time backing up/reinstalling].

Specs:
Win 7 64 bit SP1    [On WD-5001AALS 500GB]
[This 19.43 gb drive was previously used for Win xp sp3. I fully formatted it and installed win 7 on it.]

Ram 4gb

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what prompted you to have so many partitions?

Comment: @Canadian Luke, Win 7 prompted me! :]. Had to spend most of my time figuring out where the space went, sick of this now but due to so many installed s/w I can't clean install or mess with the setup.

Comment: Have you tried converting the disk to Dynamic? This will prevent older versions of Windows from booting off that drive without reinstalling them, but if you ONLY use Windows 7, it may be a viable option...

Comment: See http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/109301-cant-delete-free-space-partition.html and http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/291215-32-deleted-drive-free-space-create-simple-volume might be of some help.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I didn't knew about this, I will try but I do have a win xp that i use for some old h/w. Are you sure I will be able to install it and use it again after making win 7 drive dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are facing the error  while trying to increase the volume /extended volume

Please follow the below steps

(i) Open the server Manager by right clicking on the My Computer and then choosing Manage.

(ii)Now click on the storage listed on the left side and then right click on the disk Management and choose Rescan Disks.

(iii) Once it is run,Try to create volume

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys, i thought i would be notified via email. Thanks for the reply, let me check this too.